What is the method to Fill Gaps in an SVG Path with Color?
I’m not entirely sure if this is the right forum for my question, but I’m looking for assistance with SVG graphics in JavaScript. Specifically, I need a method or, ideally, a script that can help me fill the background of an SVG path that has gaps in it with a solid color.
I’ve attached an image to illustrate the SVG path I’m working with. My goal is to trace a background fill that covers the entire shape, including filling in the gaps.
Any suggestions or examples of how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!


It depends on how your path/SVG is constructed, but just discard the inner sub-paths by truncating the 'd' attribute at the second M/m command.

Here's what I ended up doing based on @Xrott's suggestion of I quote:

Discarding the inner sub-paths by truncating the 'd' attribute at the
second M/m command

Using Inkscape
The idea is to break appart the path and merge back the pieces using union.

select the path
copy ( ctrl + c )
paste in place ( ctrl + alt + v )
select the copy
break appart ( shift + ctrl + k)
select all the pieces
union ( ctrl + "+" )

Using DOM Parser
function splitPath(svgData){

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    
    const svgDoc = parser.parseFromString(svgData, "image/svg+xml");
    
    // split paths
    
    const paths = svgDoc.querySelectorAll('path');
    
    paths.forEach( path => {
        
        const dAttr = path.getAttribute('d');
        
        if (!dAttr) return;

        // Split 'd' attribute at each "M" command (keeping the "M" as the start of each segment)
        
        const segments = dAttr.split(/(?=M)/).filter(seg => seg.trim() !== "");

        if (segments.length > 1) {
            
            // Create new <path> elements for each segment
            const parent = path.parentNode;
            
            segments.forEach(segment => {
                
                const newPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
                
                newPath.setAttribute('d', segment.trim());

                // Copy critical attributes from original path
                
                criticalAttrs.forEach(attr => {
                    
                    if (path.hasAttribute(attr)) {
                        
                        newPath.setAttribute(attr, path.getAttribute(attr));
                    }
                });

                // Append the new path to the parent
                
                parent.insertBefore(newPath, path);
            });

            // Remove the original path
            
            parent.removeChild(path);
        }
    });
    
    const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    
    optimizedSvg = serializer.serializeToString(svgDoc);
}

Using Fabric.js
This is not a performant solution but the core concept stays the same, so I'm sharing it here in case it helps someone else:
groupObj.getObjects().forEach(function(childObj) {
    
    // Check if the child object is a path
    if (childObj.type === 'path') {
        
        // Clone the path object to process it without modifying the original
        childObj.clone(function(clonedChild) {
            
            const pathData = clonedChild.path;
            let newPathData = [];
            const clonedPaths = [];
            
            // Iterate through the path commands and start a new path at every 'M'/'m'
            for (let i = 0; i < pathData.length; i++) {
                const command = pathData[i];
                const commandType = command[0]; // First element is the command type (e.g., 'M', 'L', etc.)
                
                // Start a new path when we hit 'M' or 'm' and there are existing commands in newPathData
                if ((commandType === 'M' || commandType === 'm') && newPathData.length > 0) {
                    // Create a new path object from the accumulated commands
                    const newPathObject = new fabric.Path(newPathData, {
                        fill: 'black',
                        strokeWidth: 0                        
                    });
                    
                    // Add the new path object to the array of cloned paths
                    clonedPaths.push(newPathObject);
                    
                    // Reset newPathData for the next segment
                    newPathData = [];
                }
                
                // Add the current command to the path segment
                newPathData.push(command);
            }
            
            // Add the last path segment if there are remaining commands
            if (newPathData.length > 0) {
                const newPathObject = new fabric.Path(newPathData, {
                    fill: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 0
                });
                clonedPaths.push(newPathObject);
            }
            
            // Add each segmented path to the new group or desired group container
            clonedPaths.forEach(path => {
                clonedGroup.add(path);
            });
        });
    }
});


This only works since the outer path is defined first in the d attribute

You're right :( I'm currently exploring other options and will either update the answer or remove it if I can't find a better solution. In the meantime, I've summarized the alternatives I've tested so far here: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/discussions/10231
